# How do I prevent writing url's inside my input field using jQuery validation?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

We are using https://jqueryvalidation.org/ library to validate the contact form on our website.

The details will be sent to a `3rd party web service`

```
jQuery("#contactform").validate({ // initialize the plugin
    rules: {
        name: {required:true},
        email: {required:true},
        phonenumber: {required:true}
    },
    submitHandler: function(form, evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        var name = jQuery('#name').val();
        var email = jQuery('#email').val();
        var phonenumber = jQuery('#phonenumber').val();
        var contactform_url = jQuery("#contactform").attr('action');

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: contactform_url,
            cache: false,
            data: {
                name: name,
                email: email,
                phonenumber: phonenumber
            },
            beforeSend: function() {
            }
        }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        });

    }
});
```

**Problem**: The current validation cannot prevent a user to input a `url` to the `name` input field

so `var name = jQuery('#name').val();` can have a value of `https://www.google.com/`

Do you know how can I avoid users to input a `link` or `url` to our `name` input field or at least convert the url into a `string`?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Dhruv, please don't post answers in comments.

Comment: @Dhruv You should post that as an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @MrPromethee I have posted please check

Comment: @cabrerahector Sorry for the inconvenient.

Answer (score 0):

Try with following code hope it will work for you

```
$('#name').on('input', function() {
    var input=$(this);
    if (input.val().substring(0,4)=='www.'){input.val('http://www.'+input.val().substring(4));}
        var re = /(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&\/~+#-])?/;
        var is_name=re.test(input.val());
            if(is_name){
                alert('valid');
            }
        }
        else{
            alert('invalid');
        }
    });
```

Your second condition ful fill here

```
var url = "google.com";

var lastCom = url.slice(-3);

alert(lastCom); // "com"
```

Comment: If you face any error then share, I will try to resolve.

Comment: thanks for the response. Can you please update your code to also detect google.com or urls that don't contain www. or http or https ?

Comment: @Conan Carroll why not simply check for "." ...?

Comment: Can you please write your answer?